# Get exit code whilst also buffering stdout from subcommand

Tags: bash, shell, exit-status

I would like get the stdout from a command while also getting the exit code. I can buffer all the stdout and also send stdout out to the terminal with:

```
 gp_result="$(git push 2>&1 | tee -a /dev/stdout)"
```

but how can I get the exit code of the subcommand too? Is this the best way:

```
gp_result="$(
   (git push 2>&1 | tee -a /dev/stdout)
   exit_code="$?"
   echo
   echo "exit code: $exit_code"
)"
```

and then parsing the output?

Comment: `set -o pipefail`, the `$PIPESTATUS` array. I'm sure this has been asked before. `set -o pipefail; foo=$(exit 13 | echo no); echo $?` => `13`.

Comment: got it but I didn't think that worked for subshells, perhaps it does

Comment: Do you have an example where `pipefail` doesn't work in subshells?